# How to add permissions to an App registration using graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am registering apps in Azure AD B2C dynamically from web application, I need to add permissions 'openid' and 'offline-access' to every app is registered through Graph API from my web backend.
and also I want to grant admin consent programmatically using graph API.
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

An Azure AD tenant administrator must explicitly grant these permissions by making a call to the admin consent endpoint. For more info - [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint).

Related links:

- [Grant permissions to an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/security-authorization#grant-permissions-to-an-application)
- [How to Grant Admin Consent for app roles using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175681/how-to-grant-admin-consent-for-app-roles-using-graph-api)
- [Requesting consent for an entire tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)
- [Azure Active Directory consent requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/consentrequests-root?view=graph-rest-1.0)