# Grant Admin Consent using Microsoft Graph API - Java

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an application using graph API and I have assigned them permission - both delegated and application...

```
    ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal = graphClient.servicePrincipals(resSerPrinId)
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    
    List<AppRole> appRoles = servicePrincipal.appRoles;
    List<PermissionScope> scopes = servicePrincipal.oauth2PermissionScopes;
    
    List<ResourceAccess> raList = new ArrayList<ResourceAccess>();
    
    for (AppRole appRole : appRoles) {
        ResourceAccess access = new ResourceAccess();
        access.id = appRole.id;
        access.type = "Role";
        raList.add(access);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Roles added...");
    
    for (PermissionScope permissionScope : scopes) {
        ResourceAccess access = new ResourceAccess();
        access.id = permissionScope.id;
        access.type = "Scope";
        raList.add(access);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Scopes added...");
    
    RequiredResourceAccess reqResAccess = new RequiredResourceAccess();
    reqResAccess.resourceAccess = raList;
    reqResAccess.resourceAppId = resSerPrinAppClientId;
    
    List<RequiredResourceAccess> rraList = new ArrayList<RequiredResourceAccess>();
    rraList.add(reqResAccess);
    
    Application application = graphClient.applications(clientAppObjId)
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    
    application.requiredResourceAccess = rraList;
    
    graphClient.applications(clientAppObjId)
    .buildRequest()
    .patch(application);
```

Here in the code above, **resSerPrinId** is resource service principal Id which has app roles in manifest and a scope in "expose an api" section...

So I am pulling out appRoles and oauth2Permission from that resource service principal and sending them to client service principal...

In the UI I am seeing that the permissions do not have grant...

[image]

Is it possible to give them admin grant using some graph API or or manually loading these permission and then giving them admin grant...or do I need to always use the UI to do it...?

Comment: Found a way...will share with community in a while...

Comment: did you share the solution? :D

Comment: @MathiasHaugsbø Will share tomorrow first thing (in 6-7 hours), on a leave today, no access to my laptop :)

Comment: @MathiasHaugsbø have added the answer please go through...it's 3 am in my country gosh I need to sleep ciao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have basically 2 types of permissions - roles (application)/scope (delegated)

So to provide "grant admin consent" to your delegated permissions, use the below snippet

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

OAuth2PermissionGrant oAuth2PermissionGrant = new OAuth2PermissionGrant();
oAuth2PermissionGrant.clientId = "clientId-value";
oAuth2PermissionGrant.consentType = "consentType-value";
oAuth2PermissionGrant.principalId = "principalId-value";
oAuth2PermissionGrant.resourceId = "resourceId-value";
oAuth2PermissionGrant.scope = "scope-value";

graphClient.oauth2PermissionGrants()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(oAuth2PermissionGrant);
```

Here is the link to documentation - [Read about oAuth2PermissionGrant here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

Now to provide "grant admin consent" to application permissions, use the below snippet...

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
appRoleAssignment.principalId = UUID.fromString("33ad69f9-da99-4bed-acd0-3f24235cb296");
appRoleAssignment.resourceId = UUID.fromString("9028d19c-26a9-4809-8e3f-20ff73e2d75e");
appRoleAssignment.appRoleId = UUID.fromString("ef7437e6-4f94-4a0a-a110-a439eb2aa8f7");

graphClient.servicePrincipals("9028d19c-26a9-4809-8e3f-20ff73e2d75e").appRoleAssignedTo()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(appRoleAssignment);
```

Here is the link to documentation - [Read more about AppRoleAssignment here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

You have to use these two bad boys right here and its done - just use the correct Ids (do not confuse client id with client principal id and likewise)

Basically the flow is - get all permissions (both types loaded up using Required Resource Access - then add admin grants to all the permissions using above code. Hope this helps. comment if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for yesterday. Found it at last.
And for future reference: application permissions rely on service principles which do NOT have the same id as the azureAd application.

So for a fully programmatical approach one should also check if there is any service principle connected to this azureAd app:

await graphClient.ServicePrincipals
                        .Request()
                        .Filter($"appId eq '{application.AppId}'")
                        .Top(1)
                        .GetAsync(). And then create one if not existing

Comment: @MathiasHaugsbø also to your surprise, when you create an app using the SDK, it will NOT create a service principal, you will have to create the service principal after the app has been created. :)

Comment: Hi Sharad. Where did you get the ResourceId from? I don't know where to get it from. Thanks!!

Comment: @RafaAyadi Hey Rafa, here you can read about oAuth2PermissionGrant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java and you can also refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java